# Same value every time when want to get size of array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c++11, arduino

I am new to c++, so please do not judge me strictly. I am trying to get size of array, but this code sample always returns 2. Also I can use only C++11. What is the problem and how can I deal with it? Thank you in advance.

```
String string = "paris";
char * array = new char [string.length() + 1];
int arraySize = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);
```

Comment: `array` is a pointer, not an array.

Answer (score 1):

It returns 2 because `array` is a pointer , meaning `sizeof(array)` returns the size of the pointer, not the array. You have 16-bit pointers?

`sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[0]);` only works for compile-time arrays.

Solution is to use `std::vector` or `std::array`.

Also use `std::size_t` for lengths, not `int`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't find out the size of an array that was created using the keyword `new`(the way you did). The size of an array allocated using `new[]` is not stored in any way in which it can be accessed later.

You should instead use `std::vector` which stores the `length` for you.

```
std::string string = "paris";
std::vector<char> myVec(string.length() + 1); //creates vector of size string.length() + 1
int arraySize = myVec.size();
```